# pprof profile with julienschmidtrouter and benchmarks not profiling handler

Tags: go, webserver, benchmarking, pprof

I am trying to profile my web server I wrote, but my pprof does not contain any data about the handler func.
I am using the [httprouter package](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter) by julienschmidt, and want to simply benchmark one of my handlers and see the pprof profile for that. For the benchmarking, I am using [go-wrk](https://github.com/tsliwowicz/go-wrk)

I set up my web server and pprof like this:

```
// Configure the server
server := &http.Server{
    Addr:    ":4000",
    Handler: router,
}

go func() {
    log.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":6060", nil))
}()

// Start the server
err = server.ListenAndServe()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

The router is initialized like this:

```
// Create the httprouter
router := httprouter.New()
// Register all handlers
router.GET("/entities/:type/map", h.UseHandler(&h.ApiGetEntitiesMapRequest{}, p))
```

And my handler looks like this:

```
func (req ApiGetEntitiesMapRequest) Handle(r *http.Request, hrp httprouter.Params, p Params) (interface{}, error) {
    test := make([]string, 0)
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        test = append(test, "1")
        test = append(test, "2")
        // Ensure pprof has some time to collect its data
        time.Sleep(10)
    }
    return test, nil
}
```

This handler is just a test, where I dynamically append a lot of elements to a slice. The reason for that is, I wanted to test whether these dynamic allocations are represented in the heap profile of pprof.

Now, what I did was:

- Start my server
- execute **go tool pprof http://localhost:6060/debug/pprof/heap** in my terminal
- then benchmark my handler by executing **go-wrk -no-c -d 5 http://localhost:4000/entities/object/map**

The request works and my benchmark also reports everything correctly. However, when I type **png** in the pprof terminal, I get this graph[image].

The graph does not contain any information about my handler and the costly heap allocations I did in my handler. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I finally found the problem!

If you are using a custom mux for handling your requests, you need to register the pprof handler to your mux, in order to get the profiling right:

```
router.HandlerFunc(http.MethodGet, "/debug/pprof/", pprof.Index)
router.HandlerFunc(http.MethodGet, "/debug/pprof/cmdline", pprof.Cmdline)
router.HandlerFunc(http.MethodGet, "/debug/pprof/profile", pprof.Profile)
router.HandlerFunc(http.MethodGet, "/debug/pprof/symbol", pprof.Symbol)
router.HandlerFunc(http.MethodGet, "/debug/pprof/trace", pprof.Trace)
router.Handler(http.MethodGet, "/debug/pprof/goroutine", pprof.Handler("goroutine"))
router.Handler(http.MethodGet, "/debug/pprof/heap", pprof.Handler("heap"))
router.Handler(http.MethodGet,"/debug/pprof/threadcreate", pprof.Handler("threadcreate"))
router.Handler(http.MethodGet,"/debug/pprof/block", pprof.Handler("block"))
```

Now I got my desired result!

Comment: I have done this, but I am seeing issues like:  
                                                                 
     go tool pprof  http://localhost:8000/debug/pprof/profile
     Fetching profile from http://localhost:8000/debug/pprof/profile
     Please wait... (30s)
     http fetch http://localhost:8000/debug/pprof/profile: Get 
     http://localhost:8000/debug/pprof/profile: EOF 

     I have my server running on 8000

Comment: what kind of mux are you using?

Comment: Slightly off topic: I believe you can avoid hardcoding all those handlers by using this: `router.Handler(http.MethodGet, "/debug/pprof/:item", http.DefaultServeMux)` (where `:item` serves as a dummy placeholder variable which pprof will ignore).

Comment: @MihaiTodor have you tested this? Doesn't your statement miss registering the pprof.Index etc?

Comment: @skaldesh Have you tested it with an older version of julienschmidt/httprouter before complaining that my suggestion from 2 years ago doesn't work? It seems that some backwards-incompatible change was made to this package and my original code doesn't work as expected with the latest release. I was able to get it to work like so: `router.Handler(http.MethodGet, "/debug/pprof/*item", http.DefaultServeMux)`. Give that a try and see if it works for you.